# Can I create many tables according to the same entity?

Tags: hibernate, entity

What I want to do is that I want to make the many tables dynamically which are the same entity structures. And then I want to refer to the dynamically created tables according to the table name.
What I understood from hibernate reference is that I can only create only one table and it should be matched exactly with entity. So I can't find any solution to my problem.

If you know any relevent open source related to my problem or any tip or web site, let me know.

Comment: why do you want this? whats your usecase?

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be separate tables? Maybe you can add a field called EntityTypeID that is a foreign key to one other table that describes the type for that record? Then you can query the objects separately?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [entity-name](http://www.martinahrer.at/2008/04/09/55/) in order to map the same entity to different tables.